# Retrieving more than one rows in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, subquery, mysql-error-1242

I need to perform a full table level scan as it should be supposed to retrieve more than one rows based on the User ID.

Since I used to get sqlMessage stating 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'.

```
{ Error: ER_SUBQUERY_NO_1_ROW: Subquery returns more than 1 row
  ...
  code: 'ER_SUBQUERY_NO_1_ROW',
  errno: 1242,
  sqlMessage: 'Subquery returns more than 1 row',
  sqlState: '21000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'CALL GetLocationTag(1)' }
```

Here is the call made to the `GetLocationTag()` code

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost`
    PROCEDURE `someDB`.`GetLocationTag`(IN `UserId` BIGINT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    READS SQL DATA 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
    COMMENT 'Retrieves Multiple Stored Location Tags, Address, Location, etc. based on User_ID'
    BEGIN
        DECLARE flag INT(11);
        DECLARE locRecord VARCHAR(255);

            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `location_map` WHERE `user_id` = User_Id ) THEN  
                BEGIN
                    SELECT * INTO locRecord FROM `location_map` WHERE `user_id` = User_Id;
                    SET flag = 1;
                END;            
            ELSE
                SET flag = 0;
                SET locRecord = 0;
            END IF;

        SELECT locRecord, flag;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

For the below query,

```
SELECT * INTO locRecord FROM `location_map` WHERE `user_id` = User_Id;
```

***How am I need to retrieve all the rows in the form of arrays & store it into variable OR How am I suppose to code such that error message should need to be resolved?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **view** to store your fetched data instead of a variable

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost`
    PROCEDURE `someDB`.`GetLocationTag`(IN `User_Id` BIGINT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT 'Retrieves Multiple Stored Location Tags, Address, Location, etc. based on User_ID'
    BEGIN
        DECLARE flag INT(11);
        DECLARE locRecord VARCHAR(255);

            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `location_map` WHERE `user_id` = User_Id ) THEN  
                BEGIN
                    SET @viewQry = CONCAT('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `someDB`.`temp` as SELECT *, 1 as flag FROM `location_map` WHERE `user_id` = ',User_Id,';');
                    PREPARE stmt FROM @viewQry; 
                    EXECUTE stmt; 
                    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
                    SELECT * FROM temp;
                END;            
            ELSE
                SELECT 0 AS locRecord, 0 AS flag;
            END IF;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: The above syntax should be like this

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `someDB`.`temp` AS SELECT *, 1 AS flag FROM `location_map` WHERE `user_id` = User_Id;

But unfortunately I'm getting
` code: 'ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE', errno: 1146, sqlMessage: 'Table \'someDB.temp\' doesn\'t exist',sqlState: '42S02'

Comment: in the else part remove "from temp" part. updated in answer

Comment: Getting Error Code: 1351
View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter

Comment: try concat and execute as prepared statement.updated the answer

Comment: Error Code: 1583
Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'CONCAT'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189671/discussion-between-nishanth--and-snfrox).